# Accessing users friends work history using GRAPH API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, user-permissions

So I figured how to access a user's friends list using the graph API:

```
<?php
if($user_id) {

  try {
        $friends = $facebook->api("/me/friends/work_history");
    }
    catch(Exception $o){
        d($o);
    }
}
?>
```

If I get rid of `work_history` it will return a list of friends by echoing `$friends`. If I keep `work_history` there it just returns a blank data array. I've granted permissions via the test user to access friends work history but nothing returns.

How do I access a list of the test users friends work history?

Comment: Hi!!! With the new graph api, you have found a way to get the friends work history ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specify that you want the work field by accessing this url:

[https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=id,name,work&access_token=...](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cwork)

Comment: I'm still getting the same result:

Answer (score 0):

By default, user_work_history is not accessible. If you want, you have to take a review by Facebook. It will be very tough, though.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

Comment: a better summary of the link would be preferable, links sometimes disappear and aren't any use in the future