# FaceBook API for friends count

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

There is the question about fetching count of user friends via FaceBook API.

I want to get the number of friends only have USER_ID of the any facebook user. As I know I can get it using FQL like:

```
SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid = X
```

But for some users this value is null or there is no value. Please advice is there another way to get this value?

Comment: have you gone through thses  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/FriendList/  Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824271/getting-friends-list-using-facebook-apis  or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516627/facebook-graph-api-get-friends-info

Comment: Sure I have read these articles

Answer (score 1):

That user might be keeping that information private. In that case, you cannot fetch that information.

Comment: Thanks. But is there any ways to get this value from users with public  access to friends count value?

Comment: If user marked that info as private, there is no way to get that value.

Answer (score 0):

You just check the following link. You need to `generate token` (by clicking on `Get Token` you will get it) with data you want from facebook API, need to select `friends` option to get the friend count.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cfriends&version=v2.8

```
FB.api(
  '/me',
  'GET',
  {"fields":"id,name,friends,link,email,gender,picture,first_name,last_name,cover"},
  function(response) {
      // Insert your code here
  }
);
```

after executing this you will get this in response as

```
{
  "id": "XXXXXXXXXX",
  "name": "Test test",
  "friends": {
    "data": [
    ],
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 14
    }
  }
}
```

`total_count` will be your friend count